# spark left join didn't work unless persist is provided

Tags: apache-spark-sql

When I use spark left join for two dataframes, the left join doesn't work unless the persist function is added to both dataframes. If not added, the second table didn't even enter into the SQL plan and the column values from the second table are simply the copies from the first table.

Comment: transformations are not evaluated without actions due to Spark's lazy evaluation. could you share the code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.